# Is there something grammatically strange about the expression 'To blame'?

Tags: expressions

Is there something unusual about the phrase: 'He is to blame'?
It seems to be a shorter form of the passive 'He is to be blamed'. Does this make it some kind of adjective with a to-infinitive form?
Are there any other phrases that follow this pattern?

Comment: "He's been accused of being to blame, and *if he **is to save** face*, he must..."

Comment: @DanBron I don't think "he is to save face" exhibits the same thing. In "he is to blame", "he" is actually the object of the blame, that's not the case with face-saving. The same goes for your "remain" and "serve" cases.

Comment: "The judge denied bail; *he **is to remain*** in State custody for the duration of the trial."  //  "Well, he was convicted; *he is **to serve*** nine years hard time".

Comment: You do get a similar thing in things like "The water is to drink (not to wash with)" which you could look at as passive like the OP says ("the water is to be drunk"), or as a shortened form of "the water is (for people) to drink".

Comment: It's a [relative infinitive](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+%22relative+infinitive%22), and they're always strange and idiomatic.

Comment: A similar expression immediately springing to mind is "to die for."

Comment: 'It's a relative infinitive, and they're always strange and idiomatic.' That reminds me: it's getting on towards Christmas again.

Comment: @emodendroket And 'Three burgers to go'. You even have to change the verb if you try to 'unelipt' this.

Comment: @Rupe Correct analysis.

Answer (score 7):

> "***To Blame***" is an idiomatic expression.
>
> ***[to blame](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blame)***
>
> 1. Deserving censure; at fault.
> 2. Being the cause or source of something
>
> Source: TheFreeDictionary.com

The idiom conveys the same meaning as the expression ***"to be blamed"***

Look at this example from the same source-

> A freak storm was to blame for the power outage.

Therefore, your sentence- "*He is to blame*" is just a concise way of essentially saying the same thing- "*He is to be blamed*".

Comment: +1 But I don't think it means *exactly* the same as "to be blamed". "He is to blame" is asserting that it *is* his fault. "He is to be blamed" *could* just be saying that blame will be attached to him in the future.

Comment: Agreed. _"to blame"_ is the definite way of implying that it was his fault. While _"to be blamed"_ does have another meaning, as you point out, the intention of my answer is to explain to OP that _"to blame"_ is not strange, and is _inherently_ similar to what he has in mind.

Comment: Understood, but I think the answer would be improved if you added something explaining that difference. At the moment it's very much saying "the same" rather than "similar".